# AWS API gateway timeouts

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I have set up serverless environment on AWS using lambdas and api gateway.
I have a script what gets called whenever someone fills up information on contact form.
The script itself looks like this:

```
const rp = require('request-promise')
const sendEmail = require('./sendEmail')

    module.exports.run = async (event, context, callback) => {
      const body = JSON.parse(event.body)
      const { name, email, budget, message, attachment } = body
      if (!name) {
        return callback(null, {
          statusCode: 400,
          body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Name is required' }),
        })
      }

      if (!email) {
        return callback(null, {
          statusCode: 400,
          body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Email address is required' }),
        })
      }

      if (!message) {
        return callback(null, {
          statusCode: 400,
          body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Message is required' }),
        })
      }


      return Promise.all([
        sendEmail({
          to: 'Example <user@example.com>',
          subject: 'Received submission',
          data:
            'Hello'
        }),
        sendEmail({
          to: `${name} <${email}>`,
          subject: 'Subject',
          data:
            'Example text',
        }),

      ])
        .then(() => {
          return callback(null, {
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: {
              'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Great success' }),
          })
        })
        .catch(err => {
          return callback(null, {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify({
              message: 'Oh no :( Message not delivered',
              error: err,
            }),
          })
        })
    }
```

And this is my sendEmail class

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

const ses = new AWS.SES()

module.exports = function({ to, subject, data, replyTo }) {
  return ses
    .sendEmail({
      Destination: { ToAddresses: [to] },
      Message: {
        Body: {
          Text: { Charset: 'UTF-8', Data: data },
        },
        Subject: {
          Data: subject,
          Charset: 'UTF-8',
        },
      },
      Source: 'Example <user@example.com>',
      ReplyToAddresses: [replyTo],
    })
    .promise()
}
```

However it keeps hanging due to the timeout which are limited to five minutes on aws side, is there something i'm missing that it's taking longer than five minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am seeing two issues here.

- you are mixing callback and async syntax of lambda
- you are mixing promise & async/await syntax

you can simply return the output, instead of of using callback. I have also changed the promise syntax to async/await.

```
const sendEmail = require('./sendEmail')

module.exports.run = async (event, context) => {
  const body = JSON.parse(event.body)
  const { name, email, budget, message, attachment } = body
  if (!name) {
    return {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Name is required' }),
    }
  }

  if (!email) {
    return {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Email address is required' }),
    }
  }

  if (!message) {
    return {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Message is required' }),
    }
  }

  try {
    await Promise.all([
      sendEmail({
        to: 'Example <user@example.com>',
        subject: 'Received submission',
        data:
          'Hello'
      }),
      sendEmail({
        to: `${name} <${email}>`,
        subject: 'Subject',
        data:
          'Example text',
      }),

    ]);

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Great success' }),
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: 'Oh no :( Message not delivered',
        error: err,
      }),
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've implemented your snippet however i'm still getting timeout on enquiry query, any ideas?

Comment: You need internet access to make `aws--sdk` calls. The lambdas deployed outside of any VPC will have access to the internet. The lambda deployed inside a VPC, will only get access to the internet when it is deployed in a private subnet and internet traffic is routed via a Nat Gateway. Are you running your lambda inside VPC?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I do not have VPC on my amazon services, doing a simple GET request to the api endpoint works well so i'm not sure

Comment: which API endpoint is working. did you try running the lambda via lambda console.

Comment: I tried with postman and in the lambda console itself, both timeout sadly.
All i'm getting is:
`Request: /enquiry
Status: 504
Latency: 29013 ms
Response Body
{
  "message": "Endpoint request timed out"
}`

Comment: my suspicion is still internet connectivity. can you goto lambda console and check the lambda's network configuration such as VPC and Subnets.

Comment: Went and checked for VPC/subnets but can't see anything, quite odd.

Comment: i tested the code. code works fine for me. please post what you have, so that i can comment.

Comment: I'm not too sure what's going on, here's my lambda function options: https://prnt.sc/r51tio and the code that I'm using is identical to one you commented earlier.

Comment: are your sending email addresses verified? also, are your destination email addresses verified.  you need to verify destination email addresses if you are using SES sandbox mode.

Comment: I have a working code, I will create a gist and give it to you.

Comment: Seems like  the partly issue was that the lambda was in eu-west-2 but there was no endpoint for SES in eu-west2, so I migrate to eu-west-1, and in the end the email was sent and received however lambda itself returned error 500

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208288/discussion-between-arun-k-and-mikk-kuttim).

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the lambdas were located in eu-west-2, while the SES was set up in eu-west-1, meaning it couldn't contact the api endpoint in eu-west-2 in SES, resulting in response 500.